# Sound not playing 3 times in for loop for timer

Tags: javascript, for-loop, audio, timer

I'm trying to make the audio beepAudio play 3 times in the for loop, right now it only beeps once there are no error messages. I tried to put the audio in the  if (timer == 0) statment three times like so:

```
     if (timer == 0) {
      stopTimer();
      document.getElementById("beepAudio").play();
      document.getElementById("beepAudio1").play();
      document.getElementById("beepAudio2").play();
}
```

but that didn't work, is it possible to do this with a for loop?

```js
let timerId;
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
 timerId = setInterval(function() {

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }

    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (timer == 0){
      stopTimer();
      for (let step = 0; step < 5; step++) {
      document.getElementById("beepAudio").play();
      }
      alert('Timer Ended');
    }
  }, 1000);
}

 function resetTimer() {
      clearInterval(timerId);
    }

 function stopTimer() {
      clearInterval(timerId);
    }


document.getElementById("beepAudio").src = "http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1252&type=mp3";
    document.getElementById("beepAudio").load();


  function start10() {
      var tenMinutes = 60 * 0.1,
          display10 = document.querySelector('#time');
      startTimer(tenMinutes, display10);

  };
```

```html
<body>
<audio id="beepAudio"></audio>


<button onclick="start10()">Start</button>
    <div>Registration closes in <span id="time">00:05</span> minutes!</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What's the duration of the sound?  If they have a uniform duration, one approach would be to simply put setTimeouts around the second and third sound plays, so that the second one waits until the first one finishes, and then the third waits until the second one finishes.

Comment: @Taplar I'm not sure what the duration of the sound is ... so I'm not sure if it has a uniform duration. I got the audio from another post on stack overflow.

Comment: [How to detect an audio has finished playing in a web page?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4620076) Don't play the next sound until the current one is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it the same audio you want to loop (the edit implys it is)..
Anyways, you could use the onended event of audio

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onended.asp

Maybe something like this:

```
let beepCount = 0;
document.getElementById("beepAudio").addEventListener("ended", () => {
    beepCount++;
    if(beepCount < 3){       
        document.getElementById("beepAudio").play();
    }
});
```

And then, when the time comes to beep:

```
if (timer == 0) {
    stopTimer();
    beepCount = 0;             
    document.getElementById("beepAudio").play();
}
```